# Can't see underscore on Windows 10

Tags: plsql, fonts, windows-10, plsqldeveloper

[image]

Hello,

Can't see underscore char in PL-SQL Developer on the newest Windows 10.

I found that line-height is less then font-size (on every size), but there is no line-height changing..

I's there font problem, or windows, or pl-sql developer?

Thanks for help..

Comment: Probably in PL/SQL developer. I'm using a slighty older version on Windows 10, and I don't have this problem. What happens when you select a different font? Mine is set to Courier New 10pt (in preferences -> User Interface -> Fonts, scroll to the editor font.

Comment: The problem is only on this font, but I need to use this font..

Comment: Could be an issue with the font. Maybe you can try it in other applications. If  not, maybe file a bug report with Allround Automation. I'm curious though what is so special about this font that you need to use it...

Comment: I can read my string data only with this font :D